# Nested if and for loop problen

Tags: c#

I am having problem with the if and for loop. The first closing bracket(}) is closing the first if statement. What I wanted to do is to close the bracket that it is aligned with.

```
startnum = int.Parse(startnumbers);

endnum = int.Parse(endnumbers);

string route = "1. ";

if (startletters == endletters && startnum > endnum)
{
   for (int count = 0; startnum < endnum; startnum++)
   {
      if (startname != endname)
      {
         count++;
         route += ("Board the {0} line, go {1} stops toward {2}",startletters,count, endname );
      }
   }
}
```

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlFYo.png)

Comment: No, the first closing bracket (}) is closing last `if` statement (`if (startname != endname)`). Why do you think it is closing the first if statement (`if (startletters == endletters && startnum > endnum)`)?

Comment: hi, so when I click the first closing bracket it highlights both that closing bracket and the first if bracket. The opening bracket for the for loop and the next if statement are not closed.

Comment: Who is _"it"_? Visual Studio? My Notepad++ and Visual Studio highlights them in a right way.  Does _"it"_ compile your code?

Comment: You have 3 opens and 3 closes - how can anything not be closed? And they are vertically aligned which should make if easy to match them in your head

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015 and I just tried copying this code to a fresh project and it shows the same error

Comment: I use notepad++ to check and it is aligned perfectly but when I use visual studio 2015, it is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following mistakes that you are going to make:

[image]

**How to solve it ?**

The following ways to sovle this problem are:
[image]

**Your Code [Corrected] :**

```
startnum = int.Parse(startnumbers);

endnum = int.Parse(endnumbers);

string route = "1.";

if (startletters == endletters && startnum > endnum)
{
   for (int count = 0; startnum < endnum; startnum++)
   {
      if (startname != endname)
      {
         count++;
         string tempRoute = string.Format("Board the {0} line, go {1} stops toward {2}",startletters,count, endname);
         route = route + " " + tempRoute;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error is in this line:

```
route += ("Board the {0} line, go {1} stops toward {2}",startletters,count, endname );
```

You have the parameters for `string.Format` but you're not actually calling it. You want this instead:

```
route += string.Format("Board the {0} line, go {1} stops toward {2}", startletters, count, endnum);
```

Because of the syntax error, the compiler isn't able to match the braces as you expect.

Comment: Thx man, it fixed it. I haven't got a clue what string format does since I am quite new to programming but thank you man.

Comment: It's very useful. You might want to keep a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) handy.